# Setting up a parent-child relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, relational-database, nsmanagedobject

I'm trying to set up a relationship in Core Data. I have a list of Trees, and each Tree will have a list of Fruits. So I have a `Tree` entity and a `Fruit` entity.

In code, I will want to list the Trees, in a table view for example. When you click on a Tree, it should then display a list of fruits that growing on that Tree.

How do I set up this relationship? Do I need to give the `Fruit` an attribute called tree? And how do I set the relationship in code, for example when I create a `Fruit` how do I associate it with a given `Tree`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Soleil,

This is quite simple. First of of all, your model should look like the following (for the sake of simplicity I skipped attributes).

[image]

In this case a `Tree` can have zero or more `Fruit`s (see `fruits` relationship). On the contrary, a `Fruit` has a `tree` relationship (an inverse relationship).

In particular, the `fruits` relationship should look like the following

[image]

Here, you can see that a to-many relationship has been set. The **Delete** rule means that if you remove a tree, also its fruits will be deleted.

The `tree` relationship is like the following

[image]

This is a one-to-one relationship since a fruit can exist only if attached to a tree. **Optional** flag is not set. So, when you create a fruit you also need to specify its parent (a tree in this case). **Nullify** rule means that when you delete a fruit, Core Data will not delete the tree associated with that fruit. It will delete only the fruit you specified.

When you create a `Fruit` entity you should follow a similar path

```
NSManagedObject *specificFruit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fruit" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[specificFruit setValue:parentTree forKey:@"tree"];
```

or if you have create `NSManagedObject` subclasses:

```
Fruit *specificFruit = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Fruit" inManagedObjectContext:context];
specificFruit.tree = parentTree;
```

Hope that helps.

P.S. Check the code since I've written without Xcode support.

Comment: shouldn't tree be the one have the to-many relationship and not fruit? the other way around right?

Comment: @lakesh Maybe I didn't explain it well but as I wrote, a `Tree` can have zero or more fruits. A `Fruit` is associated with one tree. Does it work for you?

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I have done much of that but you filled in some details that will help a lot.