# Make a relationship with one object already exists

Tags: objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, nsmanagedobject

The user must create a family in `AllFamille`. In a second view the user must create a product in `AllProduit`. While creating, the user must choose the family created before.

`AllFamille` and `AllProduit` are two different entities. How to create a relationship between them?

Family creation:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    app=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    AllFamille *famille = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllFamille"inManagedObjectContext:context];        
    famille.name = nameFamField.text;   

    NSError *error;        
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Erroor");
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"famCreated" object:self];
}
```

Product creation:

```
-(void)addProd:(NSString *)idProd    
{        
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AllCodeVente * _allCodeVente = (AllCodeVente*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllCodeVente" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    for (NSManagedObject *obj in app.cdeVenteArray)
    {
        _allCodeVente.codeVente = [obj valueForKey:@"cdv"];
        _allCodeVente.uniteVente = [obj valueForKey:@"uv"];            
    }

    AllProduit * _allProduit = (AllProduit*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllProduit" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    _allProduit.libelleProduit = nomStr;
    _allProduit.familleProduit=familleStr;
    _allProduit.stockProduit =qteStockStr;
    _allProduit.prixVenteProduit=prixVente;
    _allProduit.prixAchatProduit = prixAchat;
    _allProduit.idProduit= idProd;

    [_allCodeVente addProduitObject:_allProduit];        

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Erroor");
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if I understand your question but you can follow these hints.

*Model your entities in a correct manner*

This means that you need (I suppose) a to-many relationships between `AllFamille` (`AF` for brevity) and `AllProduit` (`AP`).

For example, create a to-many relationship called `toAllProduits` from `AF` to `AP`. Create a relationship called `toAllFamille` (an inverse) from `AP` to `AF`.

See my prev answer: [Setting up a parent-child relationship in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232092/setting-up-a-parent-child-relationship-in-core-data/15233763#15233763).

*Retrieve the correct family*

After you created a bunch of families, you then create products and you associate them with a specific family. How?

For example, create a `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve the specific `AF`. You will need a `NSPredicate`. After that, just use that retrieved family and assign it to a product. e.g.

```
AllProduit * _allProduit = (AllProduit*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AllProduit" inManagedObjectContext:context];
_allProduit.libelleProduit = nomStr;
// your other properties here...
_allProduit.toAllFamille = retrievedAllFamille; // where this object has been retrieved with the correct request
```

Hope that helps.